# DO I need to install nuget to work with umbraco?

Tags: .net, umbraco

I m trying to install umbraco but i found nuget to be install. I want to use umbraco with visual studio. so, do i need to install nuget to work with umbraco or can i open it in visual studio?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what nuget is (or what umbraco is perhaps?). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Nuget is a package manager delivering files and assemblies. Nuget packages make it easy for setting up dependancies. There is no hard need for nuget to be installed but it makes life much easier.

Also when updating versions of the dependancies you just get a newer version of the package.